# unique date field postgresql default value

Tags: postgresql, date, unique

I have a `date` column which I want to be unique once populated, but want the `date` field to be ignored if it is not populated.

In MySQL the way this is accomplished is to set the `date` column to "not null" and give it a default value of '0000-00-00' - this allows all other fields in the unique index to be "checked" even if the `date` column is not populated yet.

This does not work in PosgreSQL because '0000-00-00' is not a valid date, so you cannot store it in a date field (this makes sense to me).

At first glance, leaving the field `nullable` seemed like an option, but this creates a problem:

```
=> create table uniq_test(NUMBER bigint not null, date DATE, UNIQUE(number, date));
CREATE TABLE
=> insert into uniq_test(number) values(1);
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into uniq_test(number) values(1);
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into uniq_test(number) values(1);
INSERT 0 1
=> insert into uniq_test(number) values(1);
INSERT 0 1
=> select * from uniq_test;
 number | date 
--------+------
      1 | 
      1 | 
      1 | 
      1 | 
(4 rows)
```

NULL apparently "isn't equal to itself" and so it does not count towards constraints.

If I add an additional unique constraint only on the `number` field, it checks only `number` and not `date` and so I cannot have two numbers with different dates.

I could select a default date that is a 'valid date' (but outside working scope) to get around this, and could (in fact) get away with that for the current project, but there are actually cases I might be encountering in the next few years where it will not in fact be evident that the date is a non-real date just because it is "a long time ago" or "in the future."

The advantage the '0000-00-00' mechanic had for me was precisely that this date isn't real and therefore indicated a non-populated entry (where 'non-populated' was a valid uniqueness attribute).  When I look around for solutions to this on the internet, most of what I find is "just use NULL" and "storing zeros is stupid."

TL;DR
**Is there a PostgreSQL best practice for needing to include "not populated" as a possible value in a unique constraint including a date field?**

Comment: You could use `-infinity` as the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not clear what you want. This is my guess:

```
create table uniq_test (number bigint not null, date date);

create unique index i1 on uniq_test (number, date)
where date is not null;

create unique index i2 on uniq_test (number)
where date is null;
```

There will be an unique constraint for not null dates and another one for null dates effectively turning the `(number, date)` tuples into distinct values.

Check [`partial index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Thanks, that sorts it - I was pretty much completely unaware of partial indexes.  I guess I can chalk that up to one more knowledge gap filled.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best practice, but you can do it such way:

```
t=# create table so35(i int, d date);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create unique index i35 on so35(i, coalesce(d,'-infinity'));
CREATE INDEX
t=# insert into so35 (i) select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so35 (i) select 2;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so35 (i) select 2;
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "i35"
DETAIL:  Key (i, (COALESCE(d, '-infinity'::date)))=(2, -infinity) already exists.
STATEMENT:  insert into so35 (i) select 2;
```

Comment: I would prefer `-infinity` over `0001-01-01`

Comment: I find it more reasonable - it documents the intended behaviour better (in my opinion). I don't tink if there are any performance advantages (or disadvantages)

Comment: I thought to make it look close to OP's mentioned "'0000-00-00' mechanic", but you are right - `-infinity` makes more sence